# Linq 3 value choices in column

Tags: vb.net, linq, filter

I am having a bit trouble with understanding Linq.
 with the following linq in vb.net:

```
    Dim qeurySearch = (From P In DB.table1
      Where P.number = searchInput And P.valueCol = 2 OrElse 
      P.valueCol= 3 OrElse P.valueCol = 4
      Select P.number , P.valueCol
      ).ToList
```

What i get from this is 4 records... all of them of which are not the searchInput.
So lets say searchinput is "102" and the valueCol which is in the same table has a value of "1". Then what i expect is that it won't work, it would give me no records. But thats wrong.

What happens is that it completely ignores my searchInput in the WHERE clause and gives the P.valueCol = 4  records. As if that one is the only WHERE clause.

Does anyone know how I can filter my query in the right way ? By giving the P.Number and that this column can only have a P.valueCol of 1,2 or 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a precedence issue. I don't know the VB precedence rules, but I *suspect* your query is being treated as:

```
Where P.number = (searchInput And P.valueCol = 2) OrElse 
                 P.valueCol= 3 OrElse P.valueCol = 4
```

I suggest you change the code to:

```
Where P.number = searchInput AndAlso (P.valueCol = 2 OrElse 
                                      P.valueCol = 3 OrElse 
                                      P.valueCol = 4)
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly. I didn't know the brackets would get accepted in linq.

Comment: give me a min, to accept your answer, it has time restriction I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try including some brackets:

If you think of your query in terms of words you might say:

> Where number is equal to searchinput and valuecol is one of 2,3 or 4

This gives a good idea of where your brackets should be:

```
Dim qeurySearch = (From P In DB.table1
  Where P.number = searchInput 
  And (P.valueCol = 2 OrElse P.valueCol= 3 OrElse P.valueCol = 4)
  Select P.number , P.valueCol
  ).ToList
```

In more depth this comes down to something called logical operator precedence. This is the order in which the logical operators in your query are considered. A fairly normal standard for this is that `NOT` is considered first, followed by `AND` and then `OR`. For example see the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on the topic for MS SQL.

In your case this means that the condition containing the `AND` is checked first:

`P.number = searchInput And P.valueCol = 2`

before the following `OR` sections are checked.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, jon skeet, gave me and answer very quickly and i tried his before i saw yours.